# My WampSever 3 Localhost isn't opening up one of my local host pages (but opens the others fine)

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have a number of web-projects saved in my localhost (using Wampserver 3). One of those web-projects uses php and recently it seems to have stopped working. By stopped working I mean, it seems to load for a while then gives me the message -

> This site can't be reached. Localhost refused to connect.

I had this working before and I guess I changed something and now it's not connecting. I can access my php with my localhost password and username so the issue isn't with my local host login details.

What I tried to do, just to confirm it was something to do with some php code I had, was I changed my index file to a very simple index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

However, even this brings up the same 'refused to connect' error message.  Does this mean it's not a php code issue? Again, other web-projects in the same localhost folders seem to work.

Any ideas on how this could be resolved would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: What makes you think this is a problem with your PHP code? This sounds to me like it's not even able to get that far. Some component, starting at your web browser and up to and including the web server, is causing the connection to fail.

Comment: Hi Z4-tier.  Thanks for your message and thoughts. I guess I just assumed this as it was the only one of my sites using php and it was the only one which stopped working. But yes, I think you are right.

In attempting to work out which file was causing the issue, I created a new folder in my local host project folder and started to move the files across one by one to see when it stopped working (I.e. the connection to the localhost failed). Oddly enough, I ended up transferring all my files, and it never broke. I don't understand why by just relieved it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this isn't really a satisfactory solution, but in trying to work out which file was causing me the issue, I created a new folder in my localhost root, and moved the files across from the location which wasn't working to the new location (which worked fine - this was the first test). I ended up moving up all the files across and I didn't see the connection to local host error again.

Basically, I just created a new folder, moved the contents to it, and it worked.

No idea why.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong with the outcome.  Sometimes these things just happen and no one can explain why.  Even so your answer is somewhat anecdotal and it might benefit from being definitive, even if you have uncertainties or questions.  Are you saying the solution is to move the site's code to a fresh folder and point the apache configs to the new folder?  If so, please definitively state that this is the resolution, even if you can't discover why it works.  Developers will be scanning for clear instructions and guidance and might simply overlook this.